# how to apply different onclick action to each button in array of buttons in android

Tags: android, android-layout

hi i am doing one application here i need to disply 6 images in 3 colunmns and 3 rows.and then when i click each image i need to perform different onclick action.i teried some way using arraylist with forloop.using below code i applied onclick function into all images but here 2 cloumn 3 images onclick function working but i first column 3 images not working onclick function.but i need to apply different onclick action  to each button. so please any one help me how to apply  onclick action to array of images.

```
     game2 .class:
        public class game2 extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    TableLayout layout;
          int i=0;
           int f=0;
                Integer[] images={R.drawable.abig,R.drawable.cbig,R.drawable.dbig,R.drawable.abig,R.drawable.cbig,R.drawable.dbig};
 List<Integer> solutionList = Arrays.asList(images);
    Integer[] randomNumbers,randomNumbers1;
TableLayout.LayoutParams param,param1;
    ImageView[] plus=new ImageView[6];
     TableRow[] row = new TableRow[6];
     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp2,lp1,lp3,lp4,lp5;
      RelativeLayout linear;
     @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main1);
         layout = new TableLayout (this);
         layout.setLayoutParams( new TableLayout.LayoutParams(40,50) );
         param=new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         param.setMargins(25, 0, 0, 0);
         lp1=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         linear=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear);
         Collections.shuffle(solutionList);
            randomNumbers = (Integer[])solutionList.toArray();
              int unique=0;
               for (f=0; f<3; f++) {
             row[f] = new TableRow(this);
             for (int c=0; c<2; c++) {
                 plus[f]=new ImageView(this);
                   plus[f].setBackgroundResource(randomNumbers[unique]);
                   plus[f].setOnClickListener(this);
                    row[f].addView(plus[f], 200,100);
                    unique++;
             } // for
             layout.addView(row[f],param);
         } // for

         linear.addView(layout,lp1);
         setContentView(linear);
        }

      public void onClick(View view) {
           if(view==plus[0])
            {

                  Toast.makeText(game2.this, "view", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if(view==plus[1])
            {
                  Toast.makeText(game2.this, "view1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if(view==plus[2])
            {
                  Toast.makeText(game2.this, "view2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if(view==plus[3])
            {
                  Toast.makeText(game2.this, "view3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
            }
            if(view==plus[4])
            {
                  Toast.makeText(game2.this, "view4", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if(view==plus[5])
            {
                  Toast.makeText(game2.this, "view5", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
  }
```

Comment: how you will display 6 images in 3 rows 3 columns ??

Comment: i am also serching that one.but how to accept the answer i am not getting

Comment: Just mark right symbol below voting button on left side of answer which is correct for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can this may be problem `for (int c=0; c<2; c++)`? use  `for (int c=0; c<3; c++)` .. `c<3` for 3 columns.. And let me know what happen..

**EDIT:**

Also

```
ImageView[] plus=new ImageView[9];

int unique=0;
for (f=0; f<3; f++) {
row[f] = new TableRow(this);
for (int c=0; c<3; c++) {
plus[unique]=new ImageView(this);
plus[unique].setBackgroundResource(randomNumbers[unique]);
plus[unique].setOnClickListener(this);
plus[unique].setId(unique);
row[f].addView(plus[unique], 200,100);
unique++;
}
```

And in onClick()

```
 public void onClick(View view) {
           switch(view.getId()){
              case 0:
                   {
                    Toast.makeText(game2.this, "view", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
                   .
                   .
                   .
              case 8:
                   {
                    Toast.makeText(game2.this, "view8", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
                }
   }
```

Comment: thakyou. now i have 2 columns. but i give for (int c=0; c<3; c++) means  displyes 3 cloumns.

Answer (score 1):

Use ArrayList instead of array.. Right now you are not adding all the elements.. In **nested for loop** your elemnts are getting **replaced**... So use ArrayList... And I don't see a need for such a complex code, You keep UI in XML and still can achieve the Same.. The present code is hard to understand and even you cannot after some days.. You cannot maintain this code..

Comment: thankyou.but in this code first  i taken one integer array then that array added into arrylist(solustionlist).so what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Use `plus[unique]` in place of `plus[f]` in all 3 lines of below loop

```
for (int c=0; c<2; c++) {
... }
```

Answer (score 0):

simple **set ID** to every imageView when creating ImageView. then setOnClickListener().

```
 onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
      case 1st_ImageViewID:
      break;

      case 2nd_ImageView_ID:
      break;

      case 3rd_ImageView_ID:
      break;

   }
}
```